# Drop Down terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: guake

Is there anyway to size down the drop down terminal Guake so that it doesn't take up the whole width of the screen?

Comment: I have Ubuntu on VMware and I am not able to find width=100. Is it because of Ubuntu being in VMware?

Comment: I changed width=50%. Is that correct?

Comment: no need for "%" sign

Comment: Same width as before.

Comment: Guake is running, so that's probably why... restart PC or close/kill Guake and run in again.

Comment: Changing the source code is the right answer if we have a settings dialog? o_O –  OMG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Make a backup:

`cp /usr/bin/guake ~/Desktop/`

- open guake with text editor

`gksu gedit /usr/bin/guake`

Then search for the line that looks like this: `width = 100` - this is how the code around it looks like:

```
screen = self.window.get_screen()
height = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_height'))
width = 100
halignment = self.client.get_int(KEY('/general/window_halignment'))
```

And modify the width value (percentage) to whatever you want. By default, Guake is centred but you can also modify its alignment by editing line which looks like this: `if halignment == ALIGN_CENTER:` and replacing `CENTER` with `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

Comment: -1, No need to modify the source code. It can be modified in the settings, as seen in the answer by A.B.

Comment: Same here, sorry -1

Comment: Ok, no hard feelings ;)

Answer (score 5):

Open `guake-prefs` via Dash or terminal or right click in your guake terminal and open <kbd>Preferences</kbd>.

Now you can change your settings

[image]